# is there a way to solve "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined In JavaScript"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, graphics

I am newbie to Js just started a day ago. I have no idea about it and its pattern is actually freaking me out as i am from a python and C# background. Anyways, I am trying to spawn many circles by trying to creating an object array of it but it keeps giving me these errors. Altho when i work for only one object it perfectly works. I have no clue what to do, i looked up and found undefined means some is not initialized but everything seems defined to me. Kindly help me out a little

[![error message][1]][1]

````
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
canvas.width = window.innerWidth

var c = canvas.getContext('2d')


function circle(x,y, dx,dy, radius){
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.dx = dx
    this.dy = dy
    this.radius = radius

    this.draw = function(){
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x,this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
        c.strokeStyle = "blue"
        c.stroke();
    }

    this.update = function() {
        if( (this.x + this.radius > innerWidth) || (this.x - this.radius < 0))
        {
            this.dx = -this.dx
        }

        if( (this.y + this.radius > innerHeight) || (this.y - this.radius < 0))
        {
            this.dy = -this.dy
        }

        this.x += this.dx
        this.y += this.dy

        this.draw();

        }
}


var CircleArray = []

for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
{
    var x = Math.random() *  innerWidth
    var y = Math.random() *  innerHeight

    var dx = 4
    var dy = 4

    var radius = 30

    CircleArray.push(new circle(x,y,dx,dy, radius))

}

function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    c.clearRect(0,0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

    for(var j = 0 ; j < CircleArray.length; j++)
    {
        CircleArray[i].update()
    }

}
animate()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWQto.png
````

Comment: `CircleArray[i].update()` should be `CircleArray[j].update()`

Comment: ohh god i cant believe i just made this rookie mistake :') tysm bro

Comment: Welcome to the wacky world of JavaScript. You'll fit right in.